# Return vector from list using seq

Tags: r

I have a list `l_1` with 30 elements. To access the element, I can do `l_1[[3]]` to return the 3rd value in that list. I want to return every 3rd value starting from the 2nd value.

`seq(2, length(l_1), 3)` generates the correct indices but I am not sure how to retrieve those values and store the result in a vector.

ex:

```
l_1[[1]] = 1
l_1[[2]] = 2
l_1[[3]] = 3
l_1[[4]] = 4
l_1[[5]] = 5
l_1[[6]] = 6
l_1[[7]] = 7
```

How can I use `seq(2, length(l_1), 3)` to return `c(2,5)` ?

Comment: `unlist(l_1[seq(2, length(l_1), 3)])`

Comment: @Marcinthebox ILL TAKE IT!

Comment: Try recycling: `unlist(l_1[ c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) ])`